# Use Auth0 service into custom element with angular 6

Tags: angular, service, components, auth0, custom-element

I created a simple cutom element component and use simple service to get an jsonplaceholder data; it works :-)

Based on this simple tuto: [a6 custom element](https://codingthesmartway.com/angular-elements-a-practical-introduction-to-web-components-with-angular-6/)

This is my repo: [repo element](https://github.com/tirlipinpon/angular-6-elements)

I would like inject 3rd party [auth0](https://auth0.com/) service into the component.

But i get this error in my console when  get the Auth service inject into component:
`ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError[e]: 
  StaticInjectorError(e)[e -> e]: 
    StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> e]: 
      NullInjectorError: No provider for e!`

**Where it throw this:** 
`return e.prototype.get = function(e, t) {
                if (void 0 === t && (t = Ne),t === Ne)
                    throw new Error("NullInjectorError: No provider for " + Se(e) + "!");
                return t
            }`

Maybe someone could tell me if is even possible, or give me some clue to proceed.

Here is a Plunker with the basic context: [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5m3hCBW3NsaNPNXgmQHf?p=preview)–

Hope have give enough informations.

Comment: Have you added `@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})` in injectable class? take reference https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: Yes he is injected in root, i tried inject it too to a specific module. Also with the factory providers   providers: [ AuthService],  and even in the constructor of the AppModule with the Injector  "class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector, private authService: AuthService) {}". But add this "Auth0 service" in the custom element constructor trigger the error.